# How to use Maven Overlay with a local artifacts

Tags: java, maven, configuration, maven-plugin, maven-central

The following is an example of how to use the [Maven Overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) plugin to overlay a Java web app project with a web app project hosted in Maven Central:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
     <configuration>
         <warName>cas</warName>
         <overlays>
             <overlay>
                <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>WEB-INF/cas.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
             </overlay>
        </overlays>
    </configuration>
<plugin>
```

As you can see, the example configures Maven to overlay the project with the `cas-server-webapp` WAR stored on Maven Central. But what if I have my own `cas-server-webapp` project stored locally in my `m2` Maven cache? What if I want to use *that* (local) WAR instead of the ones hosted on Maven Central? I've read the Maven Overlay docs twice now, and don't see how I can configure this.

**How do I configure the Maven Overlay plugin to pull the overlay WAR from my local Maven cache (`m2`) rather than Maven Central?**

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:
create folder called lib in your project and copay your file there and add this to Maven

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>testID</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtifactID</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/your_library_file.jar
        </systemPath>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Irakli Charkhalashvili (+1) - however I think this is still  missing something. Here's what I did. I cloned [this CAS example project](https://github.com/UniconLabs/simple-cas4-overlay-template), and then replaced the `<dependency>` element in its `pom.xml` with the one you provided above. I then modified the `systemPath` to point to where I have the CAS project cloned locally. I then added a file called `wyatt.derp` to CAS' `cas-server-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` directory. Then I built the `simple-cas4-overlay-template` project using `mvn package`...

Comment: This produced a `cas.war`, but `wyatt.derp` is still missing from it, which means Maven i still pulling CAS from Maven Central. Any ideas? Thanks again!